# Label logic gates after using logicparse in Schemdraw library in Python

Tags: python

I created a graph full of connected logic gates using `logicparse` function.

I would like to label the gates within the drawing, but I cannot find a straightforward way.

I tried to access the segments of the drawing using `get_segments()` but I did not know how to modify the different segments and be able to label my gates.

Any ideas / suggestions?

[image]

Code source:

```
from schemdraw.parsing import logicparse
import random
gates = [' and ', ' or ', ' nand ', ' nor ', ' xor ', ' xnor ']
g1 = '(a' + random.choice(gates) + 'b)'
g2 = '(c' + random.choice(gates) + 'd)'
g3 = '(e' + random.choice(gates) + 'f)'
g4 = '(g' + random.choice(gates) + 'h)'
inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
levels = [g1, g2]
g5 = '(' + random.choice(inputs) + random.choice(gates) + g1 + ')'
g6 = '(' + random.choice(inputs) + random.choice(gates) + g2 + ')'
g7 = '(' + random.choice(levels) + random.choice(gates) + g3 + ')'
g8 = '(' + random.choice(levels) + random.choice(gates) + g4 + ')'

g9 = '(' + g7 + random.choice(gates) + g8 + ')'
g10 = '(' + g9 + ' and ' + 'ZERO' + ')'
g11 = '(' + g5 + random.choice(gates) + g6 + ')'
g12 = '(' + g10 + random.choice(gates) + g11 + ')'

d = logicparse(g12, outlabel='$y$')
d.save("image.svg")
```

Commands to execute the code:

```
!pip install schemdraw
!pip install pyparsing
```

Comment: I predict the output is logic 1. Always.

Comment: I am sorry, what?

Comment: The output `y` is always 1.

Comment: Why? And how does that matter to the problem I have?

Comment: Good questions. And yes it doesn’t matter to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is a very old post. However, since nobody has answered it so far and for others who are looking for similar information, I will try to answer the question posted.

To label the gates within the drawing, you can exploit the `label()` function or the `add_label()` function (deprecated).

For example :

```
    g = drawing.add(any element that you want).label(elementname,loc=location))
```

location could be top, bottom, left, right, center...
note : here 'drawing' is a variable assigned as `schemdraw.Drawing()`

I hope this helps.